# Types of regex's and common features

Tags: regex

As far as I know there are **basic regex** and **extended regex**, and a lot of small variants of these two, implemented in a variety of programming languages.

My question is: what are the (advanced) features I can be sure to find in every implementation? (e.g. lookahead, lookbehind, non-greedy matching, atomic grouping...)

Which of these are part of some sort of standard everyone complies to? (Is there even a standard?)

Comment: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm is a great resource and you should find everything you need in there.

Comment: You should read this book: [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do).

Comment: Like any API it depends. Look at the documentation for the library used by the programming language you are using regular expressions from.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806693/why-isnt-there-a-regular-expression-standard

Comment: @david well that's not what i'm asking...

Answer (score 0):

There is no *one* standard. I guess regular expression syntax as defined in [POSIX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) is the closest thing, but those have very basic feature sets.

> What are the (advanced) features I can be *sure* to find *in every implementation*?

I'm not sure there are any (advanced) features you can find in *every* implementation, unless you limit *every* in some way.

Each implementation/flavor has its own syntax and features. Same syntax can mean different things in different flavors.

Comment: follow-up question: today I answered a couple of Q with the only one tag `regex`. I tried to keep it as general as possible, but other answers used features (for example lookahead and lookbehind) that you wouldn't expect to find in every implementation. How did they know it was safe to use them in their answer?

Comment: @blue, they don't know. But you can state your assumptions. For example you could assume that PCRE or compatible is used. Or just state what flavor the expression is for. Or just comment on the question and ask. ;-)

Comment: @blue: you can follow this link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html  see the tables (sorry a moderator have deleted my answer)

Comment: @qtax all right, I used up all my votes for today but you'll definitely get one up from me