# Are regex engines of Java and Groovy the same?

Tags: java, regex, groovy

Now I am doing some code basing on regex in Groovy. But for creation and testing my regexes I use books referencing to Java regex engine and Java-oriented http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html.

And I am a bit afraid - Is Groovy regex engine really the same as Java one? I know that they are very close. But have they some differences nevertheless? If you know the answer - can you kindly give me some reference on the subject?

Comment: the regex itself should be the same everywhere, only the syntax might differ a little bit. you can [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) as well, also it contains a code generator

Comment: The [Groovy doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_regular_expression_operators) states: *"The pattern operator (`~`) provides a simple way to create a `java.util.regex.Pattern` instance"* - so they are using the same engine

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Regular expressions aren't a strongly standardized language, the syntax can differ arbitrarily. The differences probably won't be wild but you can't assume that some element you're used to using beyond the basics will be supported in any given engine. (E.g. POSIX classes, named captures, nongreedy matching.)

Comment: @millimoose there is a [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806693/why-isnt-there-a-regular-expression-standard) but as the answer states as well, not everyone seems to follow it

Comment: @UnholySheep sorry, you are repeating an answer, given earlier.

Comment: @Gangnus It's a coincidence of timestamps, neither of us had seen either one's answer/comment when we posted.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - That's what I meant by them not being "strongly" standardized. Yes, technically a POSIX standard exists, but compliance is mostly relevant to implementing the OS support for REs in a Unix. In general people making RE libraries probably just crib extensions from Perl that seem useful and feasible to implement to them, and I'm guessing everyone using REs often probably relies on a few features outside the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [language documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_regular_expression_operators):

> The pattern operator (~) provides a simple way to create a `java.util.regex.Pattern` instance.

I can't find phrasing where the documentation guarantees this is the regular expression engine used for pattern matching throughout Groovy; I do however find it very, very, *very*, **very** unlikely Groovy would use two RE engines in its implementation now or switch the RE engine in the future.

Comment: It is very good that you have the reference do the Groovy documentation. +1. So, if I use ~ for regex in findAll, I am sure it will be read as Java regex. It is a solution of my problem, but sorry, it is not exactly the answer to that post. What happens if I won't use ~ there?

Comment: @Gangnus - Provide an example? I'm not really familiar with each and every way you can create REs in Groovy. I do however think it's fantastically implausible they'd switch to a different RE engine if they use Java's for the language-level RE support.

Comment: Example: name.replaceAll(/(\d+)\z/){fullMatch, lastIndex -> ... Have I use ~ before the /../ regex pattern?

Comment: Yes, it is much probable that Groovy has the very Java engine, but we can't count on our thoughts on probability talking about realization.

Comment: @Gangnus assuming that `name` is a string, it's an instance of `java.lang.String` (so `replaceAll` is the method defined in the Java class) with the `/(\d+)\z/` being a [Slashy String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_slashy_string)

Comment: @UnholySheep No, we use here not replaceAll(regex), but replaceAll (regex, closure), that is from StringGroovyMethods

Comment: @Gangnus if you [check the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.4/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.java#StringGroovyMethods.replaceAll%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%29) you see that that method uses `Pattern.compile` which is part of `java.util.regex.Pattern`

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you very much for looking into the code, but, sorry, the code can be changed without a word, if it is not supported in some declaration in the documentation. And that piece of documentation is what I am looking for. Whithout that I can be sure I can count on the equivalence NOW, but not in future.  If you would put your source code research (with citation) as an answer, I would surely upvote it, but still, it is not the answer...

Comment: @Gangnus **Groovy uses `java.util.regex.Pattern`. Period.** The set of methods Groovy provides is *different*, but **the regex flavor is the same**.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, but where do you know it from? Could you put that piece of info as an answer and I will gladly mark it as such.

Comment: @Gangnus There are two perfectly valid answers already. I can't find any reason not to believe the sources quoted. Unless you explicitly use some unknown Groovy build, or a different regex library, you are using `java.util.regex.Pattern` in Groovy.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Both answers allow me to change the code so that I will be sure that HERE Groovy uses Java regex engine. But I would like to know if it ALWAYS uses Java regex engine. Just as in your comment. But your comment has no references. Or to know some context where they are not the same.

Comment: @Gangnus I have not heard of different Groovy flavors. Everywhere, it is written that Groovy is based on Java. If any time in the future, Groovy regex engine is changed to say PCRE, surely there may be a difference. But now, are there different Groovy flavors? Are there different Javas? C#s? Pythons? This is becoming an opinion-based question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So, that point is not openly set in the Groovy documentation, but we can guaranteer the use of the Java regex engine by the mentioned measures?

Comment: @millimoose Could you add to the answer the fact that the question if Groovy always uses the Java regex engine, is not openly constated in the Groovy documentation?

Comment: @Gangnus Sure, even though I refuse to believe it's a valid concern. Like I would literally bet money the thing you're worrying about is not going to happen anytime soon.

Comment: @millimoose On the contrary. I love the strict rules of ANSI C, where it is strictly defined what is set by language, what is not set by language. but must be set by a compiler, what can be set by the compiler, but needn't and, finally, what is totally undefined. It is much more honest than to say a rule without not defining its context. And where it is possible, I am trying to understand the working rules in the most strict way.

Comment: And I respect your preference, but it doesn't change that the scenario you propose will, by my estimation, not come to pass in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

"Because Groovy is based on Java, you can use Java's regular expression package with Groovy. Simply put import java.util.regex.* at the top of your Groovy source code. Any Java code using regular expressions will then automatically work in your Groovy code too."
[Source: regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/groovy.html)

Comment: Oh, thank you, that can be a solution. Using that import I simply use Java's regex engine in Groovy. But still, I would like to know (out of pure curiosity), if their regex engines are same or not? Do I have to use your import?

Comment: In this case i would like to reference to the post of @millimoose . To avoid double-posting

Comment: I think, the way mentioned by you, is independent and useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a groovy example to match regex along with `find` :

```
assert ['abc'] == ['def', 'abc', '123'].findAll { it =~ /abc/ }
```

You can find more examples from [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html) (including above sample), thanks to Mr. Haki.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question whether Groovy uses the same regex engine as Java or if they differ?

Comment: Oh, thank you, I can use regexes in Groovy, the problem is absolutely different. BTW, your variant is concluded in @millimoose answer already.